# HTML5 How to use Dropzone

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

Hello I am to make a Dropzone for List of People.
I am interested in using Html5's new Dropzone, only thing is there's no clear explaination to what it is, on how to use it nor examples in w3schools.com

All it gave was its values: Copy, Move, link.
is somebody kind enough to give an simple and easy to understand example?

My idea is to have 2 divs, div1 where it contains list of Students and div2 for List of currently enrolled students to a subject.
I'd like users to be able to drag students from div1 to div2, and its name be shown on div2.
is that possible?

Comment: Why would you need examples on w3schools.com? Try http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/drag-and-drop/

Comment: @robertc your comment was really useful! way way better than what w3schools gave. :)
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit late to the game here, you can't use [dropzone] out the box as it isn't supported on any browsers.  See [my project](https://github.com/stevendwood/html5-dropzone) which is an attempt to implement what I think the spec. means. You can easily achieve your use case with it.

Comment: Thanks, yeah a bit late but your project I think was what I was looking for.